# How to search epoch timestamps in a SQLite database by inconclusive date range?

Tags: database, sqlite, search, timestamp

I have a SQLite database that has looks like:

```
timestamp    user   action  
------------------------------
1236643200   John   ABC
1236711411   Bob    ABC
1236711516   Bob    ABC
1236711518   Sarah  ABC
1236711519   John   ABC
```

I want to search by a date range like so `08/15/2016-09/30/2016`. What is the most elegant way of doing that?

This does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE (timestamp BETWEEN 09/30/2016 AND 08/15/2016)
```

And that is because the timestamps are stored as integers. So how can I convert `09/30/2016` to an epoch timestamp before doing the search? I tried using `strftime` and there are many options but I just can't do what I want with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite` can understand dates of the form `YYYY-MM-DD`. For example:

```
sqlite> SELECT strftime('%s','2016-09-30');
1475193600
```

If you don't have the date in that form, you have to convert it first:

```
sqlite> SELECT strftime('%s',substr('09/30/2016',7,4) || '-' || substr('09/30/2016',1,2) || '-' || substr('09/30/2016',4,2));
1475193600
```

Note, that if you are working with a date range, you might have to add 1 day to the upper bound of the range to ensure that it includes the last day in its entirety. So you would have something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp BETWEEN strftime('%s','2016-08-15') AND strftime('%s','2016-09-30','1 day')
```